# Oracle SQL Query different results

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

We are running Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production/

We have the following query which is a join between a user, user_learning and user_group table.

```
select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.surname, u.client_company_id, u.username,   
       ul.completion_status 
from user u, user_learning ul 
where 
      u.user_id = ul.user_id (+) 
  and (ul.enrolment_status = 'E'   or ul.enrolment_status is null) 
  and upper(u.surname) like 'CART%'
  and ((u.user_id is not null  and (u.client_company_id in ('ABCDEF') )  
       and exists (select 1 
                   from user_group g
                   where g.user_id = u.user_id 
                     and g.group_id in  
                         (215479,215480,221934,39901,45709,45710,45712,
                         45713,45714,45715,45716,45717,45718)
                   ) 
       ) 
       or (u.user_id = 1209289 or u.manager_id = 1209289)
      )
  order by u.client_company_id, u.surname, u.first_name, u.user_id;
```

This query gives 0 results and 198 each time it runs alternating and sometimes returning 0 etc..

Some background info on the tables and what we have tried so far,

```
-- Gives 1184415 records
select count(1) from user; 

-- Gives 7789332 records
select count(1) from user_learning; 

-- Gives 3278032
select count(1) from user_group;
```

There is an index on user table column surname as follows,
    CREATE INDEX IDX_USER_UPPER ON USER (UPPER("SURNAME")) 
    USER_GROUP contains group_id and user_id as PRIMARY KEY
    user_id is the PRIMARY KEY in the USER table

What we have noticed is when we drop the IDX_USER_UPPER index and run the query the results are consistent always. But having the index means after a time the results are not the same. 
We had the doubt on the index and droping it and running the query seemed to produce consistent result but that was up to a little time then again the query stoped giving consistent result. We change the upper(u.surname) like 'CART%' to 'CAR%' or 'CARTE%' etc... then it slowly starts behaving strange giving 0 or more records etc..

The explain plan indicates when the index is used at times and at times its not used.. so maybe this index is not the issue...??

I have tried gathering stats on the index and rebuilding the index

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER_UPPER ON USER (UPPER("SURNAME")) 
alter index IDX_USER_UPPER compute statistics
alter index IDX_USER_UPPER rebuild
```

have also run the following but still the same effect except when the index is dropped it seems to work for a while.

```
exec DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'USER');
exec DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'USER_LEARNING');
exec DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'USER_GROUP');

exec DBMS_STATS.GATHER_INDEX_STATS ( 'SCHEMA', 'IDX_USER_UPPER');
-- note SCHEMA is our schema name

-- indicates Last_analysed is updated ...
select table_name, owner, to_char(last_analyzed, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
from   dba_tables 
where table_name IN ('USER', 'USER_LEARNING', 'USER_GROUP')
```

another option I tried is by setting the "_no_or_expansion" flag as follows,

```
alter session set "_no_or_expansion"=true;
-- no impact to the query though
```

(Sometimes it looks like when the index is dropped the query keeps returning consistent data when 'CAR%', "CART%', 'CARTE%', 'CARTER%' which ever is queried - strange )

but still the strange behavior exists any thoughts or questions or solutions, if any of you have come across something similar to this please.

---

running 
    select * from dba_autotask_client
shows
     auto optimizer stats collection    ENABLED

Comment: This will a key for you: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-index-usage-like-operator-domain-indexes/

Comment: You have indicated in the blog that "The SEARCH-STRING% will perform INDEX RANGE SCAN data in least possible time. Here the optimizer knows ,where the string gets started (means it know the predicate),so It used Index Range Scan"  The problem I am facing is the search string is "SEARCH-STRING%" type and even if it uses the index the results keep differing. When the index is dropped it goes for a full table scan and it kind of works but will slow down the process.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like buggy behaviour, but be very careful that you are not using any views/functions with nondeterministic behaviour in them (i.e. that are stateful in some way, so that they don't always return the same answer with the same inputs).

I'd have a look at the execution plans your queries are using: a possibility is that different execution plans are being used, and the plans give different results. They shouldn't do, unless you have messed up and your queries are nondeterministic, but if so, you will be able to pin this down and complain to Oracle.

one way is to run your query and then run

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'advanced'));
```

which *should* show the execution plan for the last thing run in your session, but sadly won't work in PL/SQL developer or other tools that silently run queries either side of yours to fetch DBMS_OUTPUT and so on (the 'last' query run in your session won't be the one you gave it)

Otherwise do something like

```
select * from v$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like '%client_company_id%';
```

... put something that is very discriminating from your query text in the like clause - I chose client_company_id as an example but I've no idea how common that is in your queries. Either way, with a bit of effort you should be able to see the row or rows in v$sql that correspond to your query, and find the sql_id. This is a hash of the sql text so the same query text (identical down to whitespace and so on) will always produce the same sql_id.

Then you can do
    select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(, 0, format=>'advanced');

If you have multiple rows in v$sql with the same sql_id, then that is a strong indicator that multiple execution plans have been spawned for your query. The cursors will have the same sql_id but different 'child_number's.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(<sql id>, <child number>, format=>'advanced');
```

Look to see if different execution plans are being used. In particular look out for 'cardinality feedback used for this statement' or 'statistics feedback used for this statement' in the 'notes' section.

Cardinality feedback is when the optimizer knows that it is making a suspect estimate in generating an execution plan, and so observes the run-time behaviour to generate a correction factor, and then plugs this in to the next execution of that query to generate a whole new plan.

It's very clever when it works, but has caused a fair few headaches too.

Either way, if you have hit a bug whereby different execution plans produce different results, then this would be one way in which the execution plan (and thus results) could change from execution to execution.

If the 'bad' plans involved using your index on UPPER(...), then dropping that index would prevent those plans from being generated, and so change the behaviour again.

Comment: Note that LIKE queries depend very heavily on the predicate:

Comment: LIKE 'MACMILLA%' is much more discriminating (returns fewer rows) than LIKE 'MAC%'. It might choose a full scan and ignore the index for a weak predicate such as LIKE 'MAC%', whereas it might use an index for LIKE 'MACMILLA%'. This could explain some of the variation you see when you change the input value.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw a function based index with column parameter as string:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER_UPPER ON USER (UPPER("SURNAME"))
```

try this instead:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_USER_UPPER ON USER (UPPER(SURNAME))
```

Comment: My idea behind: on index creation the index values are correctly evaluated, but when inserting new rows the index value becomes simply "SURNAME" and therefore you get sometimes 0, because the correct value is not present in the index and the index is used...

Answer (score 0):

Note on Pavel's answer

UPPER("SURNAME") should be the same as UPPER(SURNAME). You can have non-uppercase identifiers (column names, table names etc) in Oracle - and even punctuation - *provided you enclose the identifier in "double quotes"*

If you use e.g. DBMS_METADATA and similar APIs in Oracle, you will often find that it sticks double-quotes round absolutely everything, simply to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C FROM [TABLE_NAME])
```